# Drawing a path on a map and having a navigation software on my phone following it

Tags: driving, cellphones, maps, software

I plan to drive in a city. I would like to decide to decide my exact route by drawing it on a map, then have a navigation software help me navigate to make sure I follow the route.

Which solutions exist to let me draw a path on a map and have a navigation software on my Android phone guide me through it?

The GMaps phone app only allows users to specify stops:

[image]

Comment: Google maps on a laptop you should have better functionality to create your route (not stops) and then share it to a phone.  I haven't tried it for a while so YMMV

Comment: I just tried it, you can create your route on the laptop but sending to phone it resets, so that isn't an option

Comment: Where do you plan to get reliable information on one-way-streets, construction works, blocked roads and other limitations that might impact your ability to take the route that looks so great on screen?

Comment: @Sabine the navigation software can do its best to mitigate that if I can't.

Answer (score 3):

I use a map app, OmsAnd in my case but there are several others that can do this as well, into which I can import GPX files. These are premade exact routes which the map navigation follows.
When you left the track, like for roadworks, it will send you back to the nearest point of the track or allows you to indicate how to get back to the track.

One disadvantage is that it does not do spoken instructions from a track.

I know some map apps do allow to preset a route and do spoken instructions. I just never bothered to learn how to do it with my app, not needed where I cycle.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks! Do you know which program could allow me to draw a route and export it as GPX?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You can use [Openrouteservice](https://maps.openrouteservice.org/#/) to export a drawn route as GPX, although it only allows to draw along roads, not freehand drawing.  But I think OSMand only routes along roads anyway.

Comment: OsmAnd also accept paths and other 'non roads' if the settings are right, so for walking and cycling, but only if your map supports it.